# Get users with admin role from jeremykenedy/laravel-roles

Tags: laravel

```
User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
            $q->hasRole('Admin');
        })->has('posts')->get()
```

How can I check if rows have Admin role from jeremykenedy/laravel-roles package within query builder?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the way that only works:

```
jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\Models\Role::where('name, 'Admin')->first()->users()->has('posts')->get()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use: `App\User::where('id', 1)->with('roles')->get();`